# How do i exclude negative numbers in DAX query PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Column = DATEDIFF ([MailingDate], [MeetingDate], Minute)

How do i exclude negative numbers to avoid inaccurate Average Times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After calculating the difference, you can assign the result to a variable and check is it negative or not. Like this:

```
Column =
VAR diff = DATEDIFF([MailingDate], [MeetingDate], MINUTE)
RETURN IF(diff < 0, BLANK(), diff)
```

`diff` will contain the difference (as in your calculation). Then the [`IF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/if-function-dax) function will check is it negative (returning blank value in this case) or not (returning the original value).